# Windows 7 in XP Mode appears to be opening multiple application instances with Alt Tab

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

XP Mode installed on a new Dell Precision M6700 running Windows 7. Multiple instances of a program running in XP Mode continue to open as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is used to switch between the XP Mode program and the other programs open in Windows 7. Shows in Task Manager as (Remote).

Any ideas on what causes this or better yet, how to prevent this from happening?